# Backup database through function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

Here i have sql server query to take backup of database using stored procedure as shown below:

Example:

```
 CREATE procedure DISKBACKUP  @location_dump varchar(255), @databasename varchar(255)                 
   AS                  
  backup Database @databasename to disk=@location_dump          
  ...
```

Can I do the same in PostgreSQL?

Comment: No, but you can use pg_dump or simple GUI tool PostgreSQL-backup (http://postgresql-backup.com/) to make PostgreSQL backups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not.

`pg_dump` must be used.

It's often requested, but it's not supported at present, and nobody who requests it ever goes on to do any work to actually make it happen.